# jQuery : Counting checked checkboxes - wrong count

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code which counts the checked checkboxes. It works fine when selecting, but the count breaks (adds +1 to the count) when i deselect some of the already selected checkboxes.

**HTML:**

```
<div>Number of checkboxes checked: <span id='chck'>0</span></div>
<table>
    <tr><td><input type='checkbox' /></td></tr> 
    <tr><td><input type='checkbox' /></td></tr> 
    <tr><td><input type='checkbox' /></td></tr> 
    <tr><td><input type='checkbox' /></td></tr> 
    <tr><td><input type='checkbox' /></td></tr> 
    <tr><td><input type='checkbox' /></td></tr> 
    <tr><td><input type='checkbox' /></td></tr>    
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
$('tr :checkbox').change(function(){

    $('#chck').text($(this).add(':checked').length);

});
```

> FIDDLE: **http://jsfiddle.net/kAsxj/**

Comment: add is for adding an element.

Comment: @MatthewRiches Yes i can see that now. I thought it was a function to add selector to the existing $this

Comment: It is to add a selector to the existing $this.  But you don't check to see if $this is checked, originally.  That's why you're off by one when you are deselecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/kAsxj/3/

Not sure why you're using `$(this).add(':checked')` when simply `$(':checked')` will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#chck').text($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length);
    //gets all input checkboxes
```

or for the specific table with inputs you can do this

```
$('#chck').text($(this).closest('table').find(':checked').length);
//gets all input checkboxes within the table
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/kAsxj/1/)

Answer (score 1):

When you `check` or un-check a check-box the count doesn't automatically increase, so you'd need:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    $('#chck').text($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length);
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kAsxj/4/).

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kAsxj/5/)

```
   $('tr :checkbox').change(function(){
        $('#chck').text($(':checkbox:checked').length);
    });
```